# What does "Duplicate symbol: __fe_def_env" mean?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, linker-errors, aix, xlc

When building a shared library on AIX with xlc, you see this linker warning:

```
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: __fe_def_env
```

To reproduce, use this source file `fenvtest.c`:

```
#include <fenv.h>

void exported_func() {
  fenv_t f;
  (void)fegetenv(&f);
}
```

Then run the following command:

```
$ xlc -G -o fenvtest.so -lm -Wl,-bexpfull fenvtest.c
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: __fe_def_env
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the warning about `__fe_def_env` occurs when building a shared library and the linker option `-bexpfull` is used.  [See the linker documentation for more explanation of `-bexpfull`.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/ld.htm)

The symbol `__fe_def_env` is defined in `/usr/include/fenv.h`:

```
const fenv_t __fe_def_env = { FE_TONEAREST, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

so it is included in every object that includes `fenv.h`.  For that reason, if when a shared object is built with `-bexpfull` or another option that exports `__fe_def_env`, this symbol will collide with the symbol of the same name in other files.

You can avoid the warning by:

- Using `-bexpall` instead of `-bexpfull`
- Customizing the export list to exclude `__fe_def_env`

That said, the warning is harmless and may be ignored.

Comment: You could edit `fenv.h` to `extern const fenv_t __fe_def_env`. __fe_def_env is defined in `libm`